# Copy and paste rows from one WB to another, with different WB names weekly

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, excel-2013

So I am trying to copy data from one WB that I filter, and paste it into another WB at the bottom of the previous rows.

I run this report every Friday, and pull data 1 day at a time for the past 7 days. The names of the source WB will change for each day I pull and looks something like this: 20170323050000 for Thursday, March 23.

The name of the destination WB will change each week as such: WK12, WK13, WK14, etc.

Is there a macro that I wouldn't have to change each week when running my report again?

***Updated***

So I played around a little bit and this does pretty much exactly what I need BUT I still go back to the last part of the original question, is there something I can do to get around changing the " Windows(WK13 RIP.xlsm").Activate " to WK14, WK15, WK16, etc. every week that I do this?

```
Sub PackFilterl()

Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="EACH"

Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="Total"

Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Set rng = rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)

    rng.Select
    rng.Copy
        Windows("WK13 RIP.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("AFE Pack Volume").Select
            lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Select

ActiveSheet.Paste
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for with one caveat.  You say you scroll to the bottom of the destination workbook to paste the copied range, but I don't have any way of knowing where the bottom is so I just set the target to A1.  You could add another line with and InputBox() call for the destination range, or write some code to figure out where the bottom is. The code below also assumes that the destination workbook is NOT already open.

```
Sub PackFilterl()

    Dim WkShtNum As Integer
    Dim WkBkName As String
    Dim DestinationWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim DestinationWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range


    WkBkName = InputBox("Enter the Path of your destination Workbook")
    WkShtNum = InputBox("Enter the week number for the destination worksheet")

    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="EACH"

    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="Total"

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Set rng = rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)

    rng.Select
    rng.Copy

    Set DestinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(WkBkName)
    Set DestinationWorksheet = DestinationWorkbook.Worksheets("WK" & CStr(WkShtNum))
    Set rng = DestinationWorksheet.Range("A1")
    rng.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)


End Sub
```

Comment: Combine this with the function: `WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Date)` and you've got a fuller answer. Furthermore, instead of using `Date`, you could use the first 8 characters of the filename, converted to a date.

Comment: `rng.Select` is completely useless.

Comment: So I am brand new to VBA, everything I know is from other coworkers and google. How would I "pass in a variable for the number after WK"?

Comment: What might be easier is if we could create a formula for your WK#.  What was week 1?   Another option would be to just have a specific named range where you would input the wk# and it would always pull from there.